# Spring Data JPA not parsing response as proper JSON string

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, spring-data-jpa

We are using Spring MVC 4.1.2 and Spring Data JPA 1.9.0. Everything works fine but when we have custom query with only selected field for a given entity then our json response does not include property name in the response, instead it just included property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly guess, your custom query looks like:

```
SELECT e.myProperty FROM Entity e [WHERE ...]
```

The effect of this is that you get a `List<Object[]>` containing only the array of property values instead of an object that has a field with the name `myProperty` and its value is the value in the database.

The solution is to create a custom data-transfer object, which has this one field and assign the value in the constructor

```
public class MyPropertyDTO { // find a better name, though :)
    private int myProperty;
    public MyPropertyDTO(int myProperty) {
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }

    public int getMyProperty() {
        return myProperty;
    }
}
```

Then rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT NEW com.mycompany.MyPropertyDTO(e.myProperty) FROM Entity e [WHERE ...]
```

In theory you could even use your original Entity class, add a json view on myProperty and create the matching constructor instead of creating a brand new class.